# How do I keep the hover effect on the navbar when hovering through dropdown lists?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I have a hover effect on my navbar and I just added a dropdown to it.
It loses the hover effect when I hover into the lists. How do I keep the hover effect?
My current css:
`.navbar-list:hover {color:red;}`

Html:

`<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-list dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          About Us 
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="company-profile.html">Company Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="board-of-director.html">Board of Director</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>`
How do I add the css to make it have the hover effect when I hover through the list?

Comment: Post your code about your question to get help.

Comment: I just need the css to make it have the hover effect even when hovering through the lists. Btw I added the css.

Comment: It's not only about your css but your html structure is also relevant. That's why i said `code` and you tag html too,aren't you?

Comment: I added the html, hopefully you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

According your code, you need to change your css selector like this.

```css
/*
.navbar-list:hover {color:red;}
*/
.dropdown:hover {color:red;}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-list dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          About Us 
      <!--
          Or you can put your dropdown-menu here
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="company-profile.html">Company Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="board-of-director.html">Board of Director</a></li>
          </ul>
      -->
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="company-profile.html">Company Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="board-of-director.html">Board of Director</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

the css selector `.navbar-list:hover {color:red;}` indicate to

`<a href="#" class="navbar-list dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us 
</a>` which not contains the `dropdown-menu`.

so you can change your css selector or html structure to fit your request.